# Looking for Private health insurance in Canada, coming over on Work Permit

Tags: working-visas, canada, health-insurance, ontario

**Canada(Ontario) - Work Permit - Private Health Insurance ?**

Is there a way to buy Private Medical Insurance for family in Canada(Ontario) until the Provincial insurance kicks in 3 months after landing.

What I searched appears to be extension of Provincial insurance. Is there a company or plan that I can buy for family for covering Medical/Health expenses for the initial 6 months?

Answer (score 1):

You can buy private health insurance until OHIP kicks in.

You can find more information here: [Where can I buy private health insurance for newcomers and visitors to Canada?](https://settlement.org/ontario/health/ohip-and-health-insurance/private-insurance/where-can-i-buy-private-health-insurance-for-newcomers-and-visitors-to-canada/)

You can find a list of insurance providers [here](http://www.olhi.ca/insurance/find-insurance-products/)

Alternatively, you can also use a broker to get various quotes.

Make sure to go through the policy to make sure what's covered and what's not.

Comment: Private Health insurances before enrolling in the Provincial insurance is only limited to Travel insurance, which is basically limited Emergency insurance. Regular medical visits etc is not covered. Is there any plan available that can help cover regular medical expenses.

Comment: I am not sure, but there must be. Have you tried talking to an insurance broker? They might be able to provide you more insights and better pricing as well.